# Role Based Authorization in ASP.NET Core Razor (not MVC) CSHTML

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, .net-6.0, okta

My application is ASP.NET Core 6 using Razor pages (not MVC). I will have OKTA claims once logged-in. In my Blazor application, I used below tags to authorize specific HTML sections:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admins,Users">
    <Authorized>
        <<my html>>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I can wrap any HTML sections in Blazor like this using `AuthorizeView` passing my role names. How I can achieve the same in ASP.NET Core with Razor pages `.CSHTML` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `(User.IsInRole("operation-admin")`

```
@if (User.IsInRole("operation-admin"))
{
   <h1>hello</h1>
}
else
{
  <h1>bye</h1>
}
```